# Are there ways to test your MYSQL database speeds on different hosts?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, connection

I am running a game server that uses a mysql database to store a lot of information. I also have couple of different hosts that have mysql.

So I was wondering if there are any ways of testing the connection or write speed (I am new to sql, so I am not sure of correct term for what determines speed of the database) of the databases on different hosts and see which one is better? Or alternatively if there are any ways of making the database faster with some setting.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, What do you mean by `database speed`?

Comment: I am not sure what determines a good mysql database vs a better one. Do all mysql databases perform the same regardless of the host it's on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question #1: Please see [The MySQL Benchmarking page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-benchmarking.html) for assistance in benchmarking and performance tuning.

I would suggest using the benchmark tools available for download [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/benchmarks.html) against each of your hosts to check performance against each other.

Your second question is a book into itself and may not have an easy answer. I suggest creating a second question with specific questions about performance for better assistance regarding that question. Possibly at the dba site (link below).

Now, if your question is "What is the best way to load balance my database servers" You have an entirely different question, and one that should probably be asked on the https://dba.stackexchange.com/ site.